# Binding the Checkbox.Checked property to property on DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0, WinForms

I have a `DataSet` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and have created a `bool` property on the `DataSet`.  I am trying to bind a `CheckBox.Checked` property to that `bool` property.  When I try to do it in the designer, I see the `DataSet` and the tables in the `DataSet` , but not the property.  I attempted to do it manually, but receive the error that the property is not found.  The only thing different I see that I'm doing is the property on the form is a superclass of the `DataSet` that is being instantiated, but I don't even see how that would affect anything.  A code snippet is below.

*Derived Class Definition*

```
public class DerivedDataSetClass: SuperDataSetClass, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool _mainFile = false;
  public bool MainFile
  {
    get { return this._mainFile; }
    set { 
      this._mainFile = value;
      this.NotifyPropertyChanged("MainFile");
    }
  }
}
```

*Property Definition*

```
private SuperDataSetClass _dataSet;
public DerivedDataSetClass DataSet
{
   get { return (DerivedDataSetClass)_dataSet;
}
```

*Ctor*

```
this._DataSet = new DerivedDataSetClass (this);

this.mainFileBindingSource = new BindingSource();
this.mainFileBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(DerivedDataSetClass);
this.mainFileBindingSource.DataMember = "MainFile";

var binding = new Binding("Checked", this.mainFileBindingSource, "MainFile");
this.chkMainFile.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems comes directly from the way you want to use your `DerivedDataSetClass`. Since it's `DataSet`, any binding done will use its default [**`DataViewManager`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataviewmanager.aspx), which *"pushes"* binding further to `Tables` binding.

When you bind to your `DerivedDataSet` `MainFile` property, what is being done under the hood is an **attempt to bind to a table** named `MainFile` within your dataset tables. Of course this fails, unless you really have such table in the dataset. For the same reason, you can't bind to *any other property* of base `DataSet` - eg. [`Locale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.locale.aspx) or [`HasErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.haserrors.aspx) - it also checks whether such tables exist, not properties.

What are the solutions to this problem? You can try implementing different `DataViewManager` - however I wasn't able to find reliable resources on that topic.

What I suggest is to create simple wrapper class for your `MainFile` property and associated `DerivedDataSetClass`, like this:

```
public class DerivedDataSetWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _mainFile;

    public DerivedDataSetWrapper(DerivedDataSetClass dataSet)
    {
        this.DataSet = dataSet;
    }

    // I assume no notification will be needed upon DataSet change;
    // hence auto-property here
    public DerivedDataSetClass DataSet { get; private set; }

    public bool MainFile
    {
        get { return this._mainFile; }
        set
        {
            this._mainFile = value;
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MainFile"));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can bind to both dataset inner content (tables) as well as `MainFile` on your wrapper class.

```
var wrapper = new DerivedDataSetWrapper(this._DataSet);
BindingSource source = new BindingSource { DataSource = wrapper };

// to bind to checkbox we essentially bind to Wrapper.MainFile
checkBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", source, "MainFile", false, 
   DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

To bind data from tables within dataset, you need to bind to `DerivedDataSetWrapper` `DataSet` property, and then navigate through tables names and columns. For example:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", source, "DataSet.Items.Name");
```

... will bind to table `Items` and column `Name` in your original `_DataSet`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help.  When the form attempts to display, I get an invalidargument exception that the property MainFile could not be bound to in the method CheckBindings of System.Forms.

Comment: @wraith808: Yep, I reproduced your problem. It comes fromthe fact how `DataSet` binding is done - check my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I was trying to get around using the CheckBox click method, but considering the overhead and the fact that this is an existing app, I guess that's cleaner.  But I'm glad to know the reason, workaround, and that I'm not crazy for what I saw. ;)